# Catch all other unanticipated exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have several exception types that I am defining and catching (i.e. Network errors, validation error, etc) -- now I basically want to say "Catch all other exceptions that I didn't anticipate."

What is the best way to do this?

Is it just using the generic `Excepion e`?

Comment: Yes. Or you can catch Throwable, but that's inadvisable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend to write all anticipated exceptions and then follow it up with Exception, for e.g.

```
try
{
}
catch (expectedException1 e)
{
}
.
.
.
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

This would help you in taking action over individual exceptions that you are expecting and finally, when you get the Exception, you can handle it generically. Since, Exception class sits at the top of all exceptions, this needs to be at the last. The general rule is, as you go down the list, the hierarchy goes towards top

Answer (score 1):

**Exception** is the "largest" type of Exception that one should reasonably catch; as it covers anything that is not an **[Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)**.

But a word of warning: depending on your concrete context, catching **Exception** can still be bad practice. Doing that is typically an indication for one of two things:

1. You have no idea what your code is doing
2. Your code is so complicated that you really can't know what might come out of it

And for both options; that is something to avoid!

In other words: catching **Exception** is something that you normally only do on a very high level - lower levels in your application should exactly know which exceptions come out of lower levels; and only catch those. If at all, you really only want to have one catch (on the "far outside") for **Exception**. Because: the only thing that you can do in the catch block there - some logging, and an error message to the user.

Comment: There is a third option, probably the most justifiable case: you've got pluggable functionality, over which you have little or no control.

Answer (score -1):

For best practice, exceptions that do not extend RuntimeException should either be caught and handled, or thrown. There is also [setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)), which can be set in `java.lang.Thread` which you can use as a 'catch-all'

Comment: setUncaughtExceptionHandler can interrupt with other possible exception handlers in the code. They are ideally used by crash reporting systems. In general, you should not use this for catching all your exceptions ! Also, if used, proper care must be taken to pass it to original exception handlers, once our job is done.